# How can I search within many files for a specific string and get returned the names of all files containing the string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with many *.inf files. I want to search the contents of each file for the string `prolific`. If one of these files contains `prolific` then it should return the name of that file so I can do other operations on it like deleting or renaming it.

I'm new to this. This is my initial effort, but it doesn't work and I'm not sure where to go from here. (I'm sure I could have done this a few years ago but I've forgotten everything.)

```
@echo OFF

For %%a (%windir%\inf\oem*.inf) do (
    for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%b in ('find "prolific" "%%a"') do (
        Echo %%~nx# >> "%~dp0\output.txt"
    )
)

Pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a single command line using **FINDSTR**:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /M "prolific" %SystemRoot%\inf\oem*.inf >>"%~dp0output.txt"
```

Open a command prompt window and run `findstr /?` for help on this standard console application of Windows.

`/I` ... search case-insensitive
`/M` ... output just the file names containing the searched string.

**Note:** The drive and folder path of the batch file referenced with `%~dp0` ends always with a backslash. So don't add an additional backslash.